# Emberjs Adding headers into ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to set request headers for my emberjs application. 
While doing the same in initializer, it does get registered and injected , but in the request headers client_id come as [object Object]
This is the initializer that gets fired when application starts.

[Apikey](https://gist.github.com/shadow-fox/430328f48f3a6bdda6cb#file-apikey-js)
//app/initializers/apikey.js

```
export default {
  name: "apikey",
  initialize: function(container, application) {
    //application.deferReadiness();
    var data = {"business" : window.location.host};
    $.ajax({
      url: ENV.apiKeyEndpoint,
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json",
      data: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).done(function(results){
      console.log(results.apikey.client_secret);
      container.register("business:key", results.apikey.client_id, { instantiate: false });
      container.register("business:secret", results.apikey.client_secret, { instantiate: false });
      container.injection('controller', 'apiKey', 'business:key');
      container.injection('route', 'apiKey', 'business:key');
      container.injection('serializer', 'apiKey', 'business:key');
      container.injection('data-adapter', 'apiKey', 'business:key');
    });
  }
};
```

[app/adapters/application.js](https://gist.github.com/shadow-fox/430328f48f3a6bdda6cb#file-application-js)
//app/adapters/application.js

```
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  // ToDo:: Add headers so that the backend will get notify which client it is.
  headers: {
    'client_id': function() {
       return this.get("apiKey");
    }.property("apiKey"),
  },
  host: ENV.apiEndpoint     
});
```

Responses that I am getting::
[request headers](https://gist.github.com/shadow-fox/430328f48f3a6bdda6cb#file-results)

//from apikey initializer

```
{
    "apikey": {
        "client_id": "0.0.0.0:4300",
        "client_secret": "kjahsdyau89dfuaoisduoaisu",
        "redirect_uri": "",
        "grant_types": null,
        "scope": null,
        "user_id": null
    }
}

//request headers
Accept: application / json,
text / javascript,
*
/*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
client_id:[object Object]
Connection:keep-alive
Host:api.app
Origin:http://0.0.0.0:4300
Referer:http://0.0.0.0:4300/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1964.2 Safari/537.36*/
```

Comment: I don't think restadapter.headers is compatible with computed properties, you can always retrieve your property before initializing the adapter and passing it as a var reference. that will definitely work

Comment: Where should I add ??

Comment: if i do var client = function() { return this.get("apiKey"); }.property("apiKey"); at the top of the adapters/application.js file it still gives me [object Object]

Answer (score 0):

Ember Data [does not invoke values in the `headers` hash if they are functions](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.7/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L606). Your `client_id` header is not getting called like I think you expect it to; it's just getting coerced straight into a string somewhere inside `XMLHttpRequest#setRequestHeader`.

You can override `RESTAdapter#ajaxOptions` to customize the behavior, something like:

```js
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  customHeaders: {
    client_id: function(adapter) {
      return adapter.get('apiKey');
    }
  },

  ajaxOptions: function() {
    var adapter = this;
    var hash = this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    var headers = this.customHeaders;

    if (headers) {
      hash.beforeSend = function (xhr) {
        Ember.keys(headers).forEach(function(key) {
          var value = headers[key];

          if (Ember.typeOf(value) === 'function') {
            // Pass the adapter instance when invoking the `customHeader` functions
            value = value.call(null, adapter);
          }

          xhr.setRequestHeader(key, value);
        });
      };
    }

    return hash;
  }
});
```

UPDATE: The `customHeader` functions are now invoked with the adapter as the first argument instead of the context.

Comment: getting undefined now

Comment: My example assumed that you have a `apiKey` property on your adapter. It could be a computed property, or something that is injected via the container. Note that you shouldn't be injecting anything into the `data-adapter` type, unless you are creating a tool like the ember browser plugins. The type you want to inject into here is just `adapter`.

Comment: I did as you said, removed the data-adapter and changed it to adapter only. But still I cant see the headers in the request.

Comment: The ```apiKey``` property is set in the intializer itself. It is not defined in the adapter.

Comment: By adding the line `container.injection('adapter', 'apiKey', 'business:key');` in your initializer, you are injecting the `apiKey` property into all adapters.

Comment: Yes, every other components are getting the property, like routes, controller, as I have tested in one route as ```this.get("apiKey");```  And it successfully gave back the result. But not in the case of adapter though. When I do in the application adapter ```headers: {
    'client_id': function() {
       return this.get("apiKey");
    }.property("apiKey"),
  } ``` In the console if I try to output the computed property it does give me the dependant Property for the computed property but doesnt give back the value .

Comment: You should not be attempting to make the function in the `customHeaders` hash computed properties with `.property()`, as the hash is not a subclass of `Ember.Object`. In my example, I invoked those functions with the adapter as the context (`this`), so calling `this.get('apiKey')` accessed the `apiKey` property on the adapter. I'm updating the example to be more clear about passing the adapter instance to the `customHeaders` functions.